# how to make j columns matrix with upper triangle zeros in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I tried to modify to make it workable for n columns instead of 3 column but it is not working. Like changing p1 and p2 into a vector and i can't get it to work, do i need another loop to make it into n columns?

```
n=10;
p1 = 0;
p2 = 0;
x = randn(n,1);
h = [1;2;3]
t(1,:) = [x(1) p1 p2];
v(:,1) = randn(n,1);
y(1) =  t(1,:) * h + randn(1,1);
for k=2:n
    t(k,:) = [x(k) x(k-1) p2];
    y(k,1) = t(k,:) * h + v(k,1);
    p2 = x(k-1);

end
```

currently i have a working code for nx3 matrix, which my output goes something like this

t = [ 1 0 0; 2 1 0; 3 2 1;4 3 2; 5 4 3; .... ; k k-1 k-2]

but i am having problems modifying the code into more columns with using the 1st vector of the t matrix to shift t(:,1) to make it into a toeplitz withe the 1st value being the same.

this is my code i tried to edit but i was getting no where close.

```
function [t,y] = var(n,h)
x = rand(n,1);
d = zeros(1,h(end));
d(1) = x(1);
t(1,:) = d;
v(:,1) = randn(n,1);
y(1) =  t(1,:) * h + randn(1,1);


for k=2:n
    t(k,:) = [x(k) x(k-1):x(k-h(end)+1)];
    y(k,1) = t(k,:) * h + v(k,1);
    xp2 = x(k-1);

end
```

Answer (score 4):

if you just want to make a lower triangle matrix then

```
x = randn(n,n);
Lower_tri=tril(x);
```

read about tril and triu here [tril](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tril.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly it, but perhaps a step in the right direction:

```
n = 3;
x = randn(n,n);
tril(x)
```

If performance is an issue, you could optimize this approach further to generate only the random numbers that you really need.

Comment: @chappjc Actually I believe I posted it about 30 seconds before his answer appeared. It is indeed somewhat of a duplicate so interesting to see that the votes are quite different.